# How to cite the same source multiple times in a row IEEE

Tags: writing, citations, ieee

I have several sentences in a row that that cite the same source.  For example,

```
Here is question one [1].  Here is question two [1].  Here is question three [1][myOriginalWork].  Here is question four [1].
```

What is the proper way to cite this using IEEE?  Do I cite my use of the source each time or do I cite it just once at the end of all my references to this source?  I don't think that citing each of my references to this one source is the way to go, but at the same time I have other sources mixed in and I want to make sure that credit is given where its due.

This is somewhat of an open ended question about citing the same source multiple times using IEEE.  I am just learning the style and want to make sure that I am using it correctly

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This question is related but does not identify any specific referencing system: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10510/2692

Comment: I don't know anything about IEEE's publications, but I would presume "ibid." and "op. cit." are accepted...

Comment: What does the IEEE style guide / notes to authors say?

Comment: I couldn't find a clear explanation.  That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't know anything about IEEE's publications, but I would presume "ibid." and "op. cit." are **not** accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this guidance document](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010050609/http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) (See page 7) on the IEEE website it appears that you do should the following when citing the same source multiple times in a row.

> **References Within a Reference:**
>
> Check the reference list for ibid. or op. cit.
>   These refer to a previous reference and should be eliminated from the reference section. In text, repeat the earlier reference number and renumber the  reference section accordingly. If the ibid. gives a new page number, or other information, use the following forms:
>
> [3, Th. 1]; [3, Lemma 2]; [3, pp. 5-10]; [3, eq. (2)]; [3, Fig. 1]; [3, Appendix I]; [3, Sec. 4.5]; [3, Ch. 2, pp. 5-10]; [3, Algorithm 5].
>
> NOTE: Editing of references may entail careful renumbering of references, as well as the citations in text.

On the same page (7) of the document in the section referring to references it states that;

> ... they appear on the line, in square brackets *inside the punctuation*

It would appear from this guidance note that the example that gave is correct unless you are referring to different pages of the same document then you need to reference as per form above.

Also the IEEE document says that you may refer to [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html), published by the University of Chicago Press, for anything not covered in their own guide.