# Is having the same reference twice a mistake?

Tags: citations, ieee

I'm looking at an IEEE paper:

http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?scp=85135877899&partnerID=8YFLogxK

Here, the same reference is listed twice: Reference [31] and reference [45] are citing the same source. Is this simply a mistake, or is that the correct way to do it in the context of an IEEE paper?

I have looked at

[How to cite the same source multiple times in a row IEEE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27861/how-to-cite-the-same-source-multiple-times-in-a-row-ieee)

but I don't think it answers my question.

The references in question:

[31] K. Wilhoit, “Who’s really attacking your ics equipment?” Trend Micro, vol. 10, 2013.

[45] K. Wilhoit, “Who’s really attacking your ics equipment?” Trend Micro, vol. 10, 2013.

Comment: It it *exactly* the same reference? Not a different page number or book chapter for example? If so, yes it’s likely to be a mistake.

Comment: Looks like 'ics' should be 'ICS'. That's another type of common mistake. Always double check your titles in the bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's exactly the same reference, it's a mistake, but a minor (and relatively common) one. The same reference should be cited twice instead.

Arguably it's a mistake the publisher should catch before publication. Certainly automated software should be able to reliably detect duplicated references. But not every publisher has the resources necessary to run this kind of check, and since it's a minor mistake, they might not feel it's necessary to fix, either.